# Create Content Types via Powershell and CSV

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I´m struggling since hours to create content types via script and csv.

The first problem is, that I want to compare existings content types within a sitecollection and the one in the csv.

But it doesn´t work. Could you please help me?

This is the script, just to read and compare the content types:

```
function new-SPOnlineContentType {
#variables that needs to be set before starting the script
$siteURL = "xxx"
$userName = "xxx"
$CSVLocation = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Scripts\ContentTypes.csv"


# Let the user fill in their password in the PowerShell window
$password = Read-Host "Please enter the password for $($userName)" -AsSecureString

# set SharePoint Online credentials
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $password)

# Creating client context object
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$context.credentials = $SPOCredentials
$contentTypes = $context.web.contenttypes
$context.load($contentTypes)

#load CSV file
$contentTypesCSV = import-csv $CSVLocation

# send the request containing all operations to the server
try{
    $context.executeQuery()
    write-host "info: Loaded Fields and Content Types" -foregroundcolor green
}
catch{
    write-host "info: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
}

# Loop through all content types to verify it doesn't exist
foreach ($contentType in $contentTypes){
    if ($contentType.Name -eq $contentTypesCSV.NameContentType ){
        write-host "Info: The content type  already exists." -foregroundcolor red
        $contentTypeExists = $true
    }
    else{
    write-host "Info: The content type  does not exists." -foregroundcolor green
        $contentTypeExists = $false
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where exactly are you facing issue? I tried your code and I am able to retrieve all the content types

Comment: Hi Deepmala, the script always says, the "content type already exists", even if the ct does not exists. At debugging the "if" within the foreach will never reached.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement seems incorrect:

```
if ($contentType.Name -eq $contentTypesCSV.NameContentType )
```

You test if the current selected contentType from $contentTypes array is equal to the whole csv-column that is returned as an array as well.

But I don't know why it evaluates always to true... I tested it and it evaluated to false.

You can change your if statement to this:

```
if ($contentTypesCSV.NameContentType.Contains($contentType.Name))
```

You could even improve if you would compare the objects and go further from there:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $contentTypesCSV.NameContentType -DifferenceObject $contentType.Name
```